# Why is .NET using more memory on a system with less RAM?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, memory-management, garbage-collection

We have two systems used for testing, both running latest Win10 Pro. One of them has 8 GB of RAM, the other 32. We run the same binary and do the same operations in each of them.

The program's memory usage (as shown by Task Manager) on the 32 GB system goes up to around 2.5 GB and stays there, with some "noise" caused by the GC as expected.

On the 8 GB system, the program uses as much memory as it can, and when the global memory usage reaches about 90-95% it seems to run a massive GC pass. Its memory usage is jumping around between anything from 1.5 GB to 5 GB. Other processes are swapped out and generally speaking the system eventually starts to slow down. If you exit the program, or stop it and press the `GC.Collect()` button that we hacked in for this test everything returns back to normal as things are swapped back. If this is any useful, pagefile.sys is set to being "managed by Windows" and sits around 8 GB with Windows recommending 1.8 GB instead (but not doing the change).

What settings, .NET or Windows could be causing this? We're not doing anything fancy with the GC from our code, except for that debug button mentioned above. We have a few `GC.KeepAlive()` calls but those by definition do nothing, just extend variable scope. The program is otherwise memory leak free, we can keep running it indefinitely and it never goes out of memory.

Comment: Using Task Manager to determine the memory pressure in managed applications is like determining how fast a vehicle runs by looking at its paint color; it simply doesn't measure what you think it does. You have to use a [memory profiler](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42721/Best-Practices-No-5-Detecting-NET-application-memo).

Comment: Indeed, use a profiler. At a coarse level of granularity, you'll probably want to look at *working set* -- that is, how many pages of memory need to be in RAM vs on disk for good performance; if that number is larger than the number of available pages, you'll get that sort of swapping behaviour. At a more fine-grained level, you'll want to look at the amount of *collection pressure* you're producing that is triggering GC behaviour. Some combination of reducing working set and collection pressure will likely help.

Comment: @EricLippert Why should the amount of total system RAM influence that?

Comment: @NetMage: There are three questions: *what* is happening?  *why* is it happening? *how* do we fix it?  Attempting to answer the second question before answering the first is a bad idea. Make more precise measurements; figure out how much collection pressure you're getting, for example, and on what schedule that triggers GCs.  Only then attempt to answer the question "why does amount of physical memory matter?"  Maybe it doesn't, and there is some other explanation. But right now you're trying to draw conclusions from insufficient data, so start gathering data.

Comment: @EricLippert My best answer for the first question is that the GC is very "lazy" on that system. I could run GC.Collect() on a 1 second timer as a workaround, but I really want to avoid doing something like that. I was wondering if there could be any settings or some registry tweak applied on that system that could affect GC behavior. It's difficult to find anything when I don't know what I'm looking for. In your words, why is it happening?

Comment: The garbage collector is supposed to be *lazy*. If it is doing unnecessary work then it is slowing everything else down! Its job is to spend as little time collecting as possible, and that means delaying collections.  You have a hypothesis -- that there are **too few** collections happening. That's possible, and you should test that hypothesis *with science*, but frankly I doubt it. Making the GC do more unnecessary work more frequently will not improve your performance, and **if your working set is larger than RAM**, it won't solve the thrashing problem; it will worsen it.

Comment: The GC is not doing its job, because other programs are getting swapped out and the system slows down. Running GC.Collect() periodically makes it do its job and unfortunately that is the workaround I ended up having to do :( I can't profile things on the customer's computer, and it works on mine.